# How do you feed multiple values into a lambda function in one line

Tags: python, lambda

For a "fun" project, I wanted to make a fizzbuzz one-liner. I'm fairly confident the logic is all good, now I'm just stuck on how to feed it 100 values at a time. This is what I have so far:

```
print(map(lambda x : return (lambda x : return 'fizzbuzz' if x%15 == 0 else return 'fizz') if x%3 == 0 else (return lambda x : (return 'fizzbuzz' if x%15 == 0 else return 'buzz') if x%5 == 0 else (return x)), range(1, 100)))
```

The error seems to be at the very end, with how I'm using the map function. How would I go about giving the lambda function a range of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few edits to your code to get this to work. The `return` keyword should not be used in lambda functions, and you also shouldn't nest a lambda for each condition. Finally, you need to convert the output to some printable format (I chose a list):

```
print(list(map(lambda x: 'fizzbuzz' if x%15 == 0 else 'fizz' if x%3 == 0 else 'buzz' if x%5 == 0 else x, range(1, 100))))
```

Comment: "*There's no need to include the `return` keyword*" - "*It's __forbidden__ to include the `return` keyword*" (or any statement whatsoever).

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. Also I didn't realise you could have multiple branches from an inline if else, which is why my code is such spaghetti. Well done, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` functions do not require the `return` statement. Instead, the code after the `:` will be evaluated and the resulting value will be returned:

```
final_values = map(lambda x:'fizzbuzz' if x%5 == 0 and x%3 == 0 else 'buzz' if x%5 == 0 else 'fizz' if x%3 == 0 else x, range(1, 100))
```